# Number of query and destination folder error

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to add a new transaction using SQL statement.

Database: **Ms Access**

Line code:

```
sqL = "INSERT INTO TableTransactions VALUES('"
        & transno.Text & "','" & cmbmonth.Text & "','" & cmbdate.Text
        & "','" & txtCash.Text & "','" & txtLand.Text & "','"
        & txtADFee.Text & "','" & txtBuilding.Text & "','"
        & txtEquipments.Text & "','" & txtAReceivables.Text
        & "','" & txtAPayable.Text & "','" & txtNPayable.Text
        & "','" & txtSPayable.Text & "','" & txtTPayable.Text
        & "','" & txtCapital.Text & "','" & txtExpenses.Text
        & "','" & txtRevenue.Text & "','" & txtDrawings.Text & "')"
```

Error:

> Number of Query and Destination Folder error.

Comment: I would strongly advise to use SQL parameters. This will help in both syntax issues and SQL injection. Please also consider taking the [tour] and looking at [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the order of fields:

```
sqL = "INSERT INTO TableTransactions (FieldNo, FieldMonth, FieldDate, ... etc.) VALUES('"
    & transno.Text & "','" & cmbmonth.Text & "','" & cmbdate.Text
    & "','" & txtCash.Text & "','" & txtLand.Text & "','"
    & txtADFee.Text & "','" & txtBuilding.Text & "','"
    & txtEquipments.Text & "','" & txtAReceivables.Text
    & "','" & txtAPayable.Text & "','" & txtNPayable.Text
    & "','" & txtSPayable.Text & "','" & txtTPayable.Text
    & "','" & txtCapital.Text & "','" & txtExpenses.Text
    & "','" & txtRevenue.Text & "','" & txtDrawings.Text & "')"
```

That said, do read up on how to use parameters to avoid the concatenation fuzz and improve security.

Comment: You don't have to specify the columns IF you provide a value for every column and you provide the values in the same order as the columns appear in the table.  I'm guessing that the error message is actually not what the OP told us and it's actually about the number of source values being different to the number of destination columns.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Yes, that's my guess as well. And then you have to specify the fields and the sequence of these that matches the sequence of the provided values.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you sir!